# Component is missing template or render function vuejs 3

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vuejs-datepicker

I am using [@gravitano/vue-date-range-picker](https://github.com/gravitano/vue-date-range-picker). I am using vuejs3.

```
<script>
   import DateRangePicker from "@gravitano/vue-date-range-picker";                                       
   export default {
   components:{
    DateRangePicker
  },
   data(){
    return {
    range: ["01/09/2018", "01/10/2018"]
    };
  },
  }
</script>

//Template

<template>
   <date-range-picker v-model="range" />
</template>
```

I am getting following error and daterangepicker is not visible.

[image: Component is missing template or render function]

Comment: That GitHub project looks unused and unupdated, and its instructions are wrong. It can't be imported as a component like that. I would look into using a different one.  [This](https://github.com/icehaunter/vue3-datepicker) looks ok

Comment: Is there anything available like following:

https://codesthq.github.io/vuelendar-demo/

Comment: https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal - `npm i vue-cal@next`

Comment: This one looks compatible with vue3, thanks! but not sure how to convert it to DateRange Picker